# Method Definition for "...:" Not Found

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app keeps coming up with a "Semantic Error" and keeps freezing/crashing.Everything seems to be stringed together fine and it launches without problem. TextFields work fine but as soon as I click anything else it fails and forces out. Any recommendations?

h.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *buy1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *sell1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *percentage1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *profit1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *royalty;
    IBOutlet UITextField *buy2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *sell2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *percentage2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *profit2;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *buytext1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *selltext1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *percentage1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profit1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *royalty;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *buytext2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sell2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *percentagetext2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profit2;

-(IBAction)Button;

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)textfieldReturn:(id)sender;

@end
```

m.

```
@implementation ViewController
        //This is where I keep getting the Semantic Error "Incomplete Implementation"
@synthesize buytext1;
@synthesize selltext1;
@synthesize buytext2;
@synthesize percentagetext2;

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [buy1 resignFirstResponder];
    [sell1 resignFirstResponder];
    [buy2 resignFirstResponder];
    [percentage2 resignFirstResponder];

}

    - (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender {
        [buy1 resignFirstResponder];
        [sell1 resignFirstResponder];
        [buy2 resignFirstResponder];
        [percentage2 resignFirstResponder];

}



int VarBuy1 = 0;
int VarSell1 = 0;
int VarProfit1 =0;
int VarPercentage1 =0;
int VarRoyalty = 0;
int VarBuy2 = 0;
int VarSell2 = 0;
int VarProfit2 =0;
int VarPercentage2 =0;


-(IBAction)Button{
    VarBuy1 = ([buy1.text intValue]);
    VarSell1 = ([sell1.text intValue]);

    VarProfit1 = (VarSell1 - (VarSell1 * (VarRoyalty / 100)) - VarBuy1);
    VarPercentage1 = (VarProfit1 / VarSell1);
    VarSell2 = (VarBuy2 / ((100 - VarRoyalty) / 100 - VarPercentage2));
    VarProfit2 = (VarSell2 - (VarSell2 * VarRoyalty) - VarBuy2);

    profit1.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:VarProfit1] stringValue];
    percentage1.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:VarPercentage1] stringValue];
    sell2.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:VarSell2] stringValue];
    profit2.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:VarProfit2] stringValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Well most of your properties don't seem to be synthesized

Comment: They don't need to be synthesized in the latest versions of the compiler;  that is done automatically.

Comment: Error message? Where does the debugger stop? Did you step through the code?

Comment: you don't have to synthesize properties in latest Xcode.

Comment: @erkanyildiz no. You don't have to synthesize properties using the latest *compiler*.

Comment: I was going to write "Xcode which includes the Apple LLVM Compiler version 4.0" But I was using mobile version of the site. And that is why I couldn't mark the codes in my answer. Thanks for editing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/aRaue

Still no luck. No errors are coming up, however this immediately shows up after I use the app and it crashes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .h

```
- (IBAction)textfieldReturn:(id)sender;
```

In  .m

```
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
```

Be careful about letter cases. field and Field.

And an IBAction without (id)sender doesn't sound good.

Comment: also you can hook up the same `IBAction` to multiple IB elements, so you don't need two identical `IBAction`.

Comment: @erkanyildiz Corrected that mistake but it seems like it still isn't the problem.

Comment: @rob_bass are you still having issue? if so what's the issue?

Comment: @iBlue No errors are popping up but it's still failing. I'm trying to find a source or trying to find something that can hint at the problem. Suggestions appreciated, otherwise I'll keep you posted.