# App Keeps Force Closing/Won't Calculate

Tags: objective-c, ios

Link to code (problems here solved): [Method Definition for "...:" Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977385/method-definition-for-not-found#comment15977861_11977385)

Link to current image/problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d11p.jpg

The app launches fine and the textfields and keyboards work just fine. However, if I try to switch between pages or hit the calculate button the app force closes and fails. Any suggestions, tips, or clues? I'm completely lost at this point in time.
(fixed)

I've gotten everything else taken care of now. However, whenever I try to calculate, it doesn't do anything. The black text label's under P.A.R. and P.P. in the first view and Sell and P.A.R. in the second view are outputs where the answer to the equations is suppose to be. For some reason it doesn't calculate. Suggestions?

image https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqlgF.jpg

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface keyboardclose : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *buy1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *sell1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *percentage1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *profit1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *royalty;
    IBOutlet UITextField *buy2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *sell2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *percentage2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *profit2;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *buytext1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *selltext1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profit1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *percentage1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *royalty;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *buytext2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sell2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profit2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *percentagetext2;


-(IBAction)answerQuestion1:(id) sender;
-(IBAction)answerQuestion2:(id) sender;

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "keyboardclose.h"


float VarBuy1 = 0;
float VarSell1 = 0;
float VarProfit1 =0;
float VarPercentage1 =0;
float VarRoyalty = 0;
float VarBuy2 = 0;
float VarSell2 = 0;
float VarProfit2 =0;
float VarPercentage2 =0;


@implementation keyboardclose
@synthesize buytext1;
@synthesize selltext1;
@synthesize buytext2;
@synthesize percentagetext2;

-(IBAction)answerQuestion1:(id) sender {
    VarBuy1 = ([buy1.text floatValue]);
    VarSell1 = ([sell1.text floatValue]);
    VarRoyalty =([royalty.text floatValue]);
    VarProfit1 =([profit1.text floatValue]);
    VarPercentage1 =([percentage1.text floatValue]);

    VarProfit1 = (VarSell1 - (VarSell1 * (VarRoyalty / 100)) - VarBuy1);
    VarPercentage1 = (VarProfit1 / VarSell1);

    profit1.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:VarProfit1] stringValue];
    percentage1.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:VarPercentage1] stringValue];

}

-(IBAction)answerQuestion2:(id) sender {
    VarRoyalty =([royalty.text floatValue]);
    VarBuy2 =([buy2.text floatValue]);
    VarSell2 = ([sell2.text floatValue]);
    VarProfit2 =([profit1.text floatValue]);
    VarPercentage2 =([percentage1.text floatValue]);

    VarSell2 = (VarBuy2 / ((100 - (VarRoyalty / 100)) / 100 - VarPercentage2));
    VarProfit2 = (VarSell2 - (VarSell2 * (VarRoyalty / 100)) - VarBuy2);

    sell2.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:VarSell2] stringValue];
    profit2.text = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:VarProfit2] stringValue];

}


- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [buy1 resignFirstResponder];
    [sell1 resignFirstResponder];
    [buy2 resignFirstResponder];
    [percentage2 resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender {
    [buy1 resignFirstResponder];
    [sell1 resignFirstResponder];
    [buy2 resignFirstResponder];
    [percentage2 resignFirstResponder];

}

@end
```

Comment: Are you calling `-(IBAction)Button` anywhere in your code? If so post them. Also it should better be `-(IBAction)button` instead of `Button`.

Comment: And what is `keyboardclose`. Post related code.

Comment: keyboard close is the RootViewController just under a different filename. Working on the IBAction to see if that makes a difference. Thanks. Will keep you posted.

Comment: your `IBAction` is under `ViewController`, not `RootViewController`. Does the latter has the same `IBAction`?

Comment: Yes. Everything should recognize `keyboardclose` as the  `ViewController`

Comment: if you still want us to help, please post all related code.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my problem with this issue. Appreciate all the help. I'll try and provide more information and more clear information next time!

Comment: @iBlue I'm experiencing some problems with the Outputs. Any suggestions? I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work. Thanks for everything!